# Parsing Json with Gson gives nullfield in object

Tags: json, gson

i got JSON that have object inside

```
{
"status": "OK",
"info": null,
"data": {
    "product": {
        "productId": "1",
        "productName": "Oreo"
     }
}
```

i parse with 
ProductResponse.java

```
public class ProductResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    @SerializedName("info")
    public String info;

    @SerializedName("data")
    public Product data;
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {

    @SerializedName("productId")
    public String productId;

    @SerializedName("productName")
    public String productName;
}
```

and in reponse i get status = "OK", info = null, and data that is product with nullfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You've defined `ProductResponse#data` as a `String`. In the JSON, it's clearly not a string, it's an object. I know nothing about GSON, but surely that's the problem...</s> Now you've changed the question so that `data` is defined as `Product`.

But `data` isn't a `Product`, it's an object that has a `product` property.

It seems like you should have

```
public class ProductResponseData {

    @SerializeName("product")
    public Product product;
}
```

and then change `ProductResponse`'s `data` to be:

```
@SerializedName("data")
public ProductResponseData data;
```

Comment: yea public String data was bad, and it was my mistake i make it String temporary to see whar happen normaly its Product

Comment: Thanks, that was what i needed :) unexpectedly that was what i try @ 5am, but i didnt read logCat proper. New experience "NEVER develop @ late night" xD